# Convert CSV to Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, export

I have a method that returns a csv row. However I want to covert this into a datatable. Meaning, wherever the is a "," I want to put the data into to a new column cell.

```
private static string ConvertGridViewRowToCsvRow(GridViewRow row)
{
        StringBuilder csvRow = new StringBuilder();
        bool firstCell = true;

        foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            string text = string.Empty;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text))
            {
                text = cell.Text;
            }
            else if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var control in cell.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is ITextControl)
                    {
                        var textControl = control as ITextControl;
                        text += HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(textControl.Text).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Trim();
                    }
                    else if (control is TextImage)
                    {
                        var textImage = control as TextImage;
                        text += HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(textImage.Text).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Trim();
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!firstCell)
            {
                csvRow.Append(",");
            }

            csvRow.Append(MakeTextCsvFriendly(text));
            firstCell = false;
        }

        return csvRow.ToString();
}
```

This is the method that is called during a button click that invokes `ConvertGridViewRowToCsvRow`

```
public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv, HashSet<string> selectedRows)
{
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        //SetHiddenColumnsVisibility(gv); enable if you want only selected columns to visible on export (not current business requirement)

        var csvFile = new StringBuilder();

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                    bool firstCell = true;

                    foreach (DataControlFieldHeaderCell cell in gv.HeaderRow.Cells)
                    {
                        if (!firstCell)
                        {
                            csvFile.Append(",");
                        }

                        string text = cell.ContainingField.HeaderText;
                        csvFile.Append(MakeTextCsvFriendly(text));
                        firstCell = false;
                    }

                    csvFile.Append("\r\n");
                }

                if (selectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && selectedRows.Contains(gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
                        {
                            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                            csvFile.AppendLine(ConvertGridViewRowToCsvRow(row));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                    {
                        GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                        csvFile.AppendLine(ConvertGridViewRowToCsvRow(row));
                    }
                }

                //  render the htmlwriter into the response
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvFile.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

I was thinking of a method that would replace `csvFile.Append(",");` or possibly one that would use such a file to store the data in a DataTable.

However I need guidance in structuring this method.

Comment: [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) is all you need

Answer (score -1):

> I tries below code to convert csv file to datatable for windows application.

```
private void CSVtoDataTable(string filepath)
{
  int count = 1;            
  char fieldSeparator = ',';
  DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

  using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(filePath))
  {                   
      csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;                  
      while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
      {
           csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
           string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields(); 
           if(count==0)
           {
               foreach (string column in fieldData)
               {
                  DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                  datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                  csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
               }
           }  
           else 
           {
               csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
           }                  

       }
     }

 }
```

Comment: If it's work fine,don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Your code didn't compile or work for me. After including "using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;" and changing "filePath" to "filepath", I still got a System.ArgumentException: Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.